# Two parameters to String.Format in a asp:HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I would send the parameters (database ID, ClientID) in a

```
<a id="ctl00" onclick="OpenModal(704520,'asdf_ID_Imagedown')">
    <img id="ID_IMAGE" src="../online/img_admin/icon_hist.gif" />
</a>
```

But I can not for 2 things. First single quotes is not working

```
String.Format("AbreModal({0},'{1}')",
```

Results: Tag unformatted with these single quotes. Without these works, but it does not close on JavaScript.

Second: I can not capture the ID of the image below and send this link, I'm trying:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" onclick='<%# String.Format("AbreModal({0},{1})", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "intid"),img_Historic.ClientID ) %>'>
 <asp:Image ID="img_Historic" runat="server" ImageUrl="../online/img_admin/icon_hist_off.png" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

**not riding in the intellisense IDImagem.ClientID**

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

in code behind all attribute encode ' 
resulta:
AbreModal(1178321,'ctl00_GridView1_ctl02_img_Historic')"
correto:
AbreModal(1178321,'ctl00_GridView1_ctl02_img_Historic')"

Comment: "not working" *how*? That tells us absolutely nothing about the problem you're running into. Compile errors? Runtime exception? What are they? Unexpected behavior? What happened? What did you expect to happen? What have you attempted to fix this already? Please elaborate.

Comment: Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: you are writing c# code in javascript onclick event its wrong

Comment: you should do this in codebehind, its too messy like this

Comment: I do not know how to call the code behind! 
tried   public string ReturnIDImage()
        {
           return  GridView1.FindControl("img_Historico").ClientID;
        }